# Button's Visible property changing inbetween Page_Init and Page_Load

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Here are my buttons:

```
<asp:Button ID="PreviousButton" CssClass="previous-button button" Text="Previous" Visible="false" OnClick="PreviousButton_Click" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="NextButton" CssClass="next-button button" Text="Next" Visible="false" OnClick="NextButton_Click" runat="server" />
```

During `Page_Init` this code is executed:

```
NextButton.Visible = bNextEnabled;
PreviousButton.Visible = bPreviousEnabled;
```

Both `bNextEnabled` and `bPreviousEnabled` are `True` at this point.

At the end of `Page_Init` `Response.Write(NextButton.Visible.ToString())` is `True`.

At the end of `Page_Init` `Response.Write(PreviousButton.Visible.ToString())` is `True`.

--

At the start of `Page_Load` `Response.Write(NextButton.Visible.ToString())` is `False`.

At the start of `Page_Load` `Response.Write(PreviousButton.Visible.ToString())` is `True`.

I've extrapolated the code for the buttons but I'll provide anything else that might be pertinent, though I have no idea what that might be as yet.

At no other point on the page is the Visible property for either button altered. The page where the buttons stop working is a postback. The page prior to the postback both buttons are set to `Visible = false` though I can't imagine how this would effect things.

So what's happening here? Both buttons use exactly the same code and yet one works as expected and the other doesn't..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's most likely related to the settings for the property getting saved into ViewState. That's the only thing between `Init` and `Load` that might have an effect on the control properties such as this (as far as I can tell). Init fires before the values from ViewState have been loaded and before ViewState tracking has been turned on, so it's possible you change it there and then it gets overwritten when the ViewState gets loaded.

If there's a reason you can't set these properties in the `Load` event instead of `Init`, you could try using the `PreLoad` event instead.

Here's [a good reference for the page lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) and what's happening when.

Comment: Okay that makes sense, I suspected it might be something along those lines. However that doesn't explain why only the next button is effected. On the previous page both buttons are hidden so shouldn't anything left in the viewstate effect both buttons? What might cause this inconsistency?

I don't think I can use PreLoad as this is in a UserControl, not a Page.

Comment: It would be difficult to debug your issue without having the all code to work with. You might set the buttons to EnableViewState="false" just to see what happens, and help verify where the issue is.

Comment: I understand. The program is huge though so I can't realistically do that. I have picked out what I hope are the important parts as I spent a long time debugging and ruling out literally everything I could in the program. By outputting the Visible property to the screen throughout my program I've essentially nailed it down to the black box that happens between Init and Load. It's one of those questions I'd just love to hear the answer to because of the apparently inconsistent behaviour between two seemingly identical buttons.

Comment: Did you try disabling viewstate to see if it makes a difference?

Comment: Only just got back into work patmortech. ;-) And yes, it worked a treat. Thank you! Though I am still perpelexed about the difference in behaviour between my two buttons. I guess I'll never know why that was happening!